# Texas Holdem poker software for LAN

Tags: texas-hold-em, software

Is there any free/paid multi-player (in LAN) poker software available? Please suggest a good one you know.

Comment: LAN as in Local Area Network?

Comment: As an aside, how much would you consider a fair price if someone were to do this well?

Comment: @ktothez yes for Local network to play within home/office network.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake Well I am a developer, I can do it quickly within 3-5 days with a dirty GUI and improve it slowly. so I dont like to invest too much, say $20

Comment: Why wouldn't filling an empty table on the free versions of Poker Stars and Full Tilt apps work?

Comment: you can create a Home Game on PokerStars

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used [DD Poker](http://www.ddpoker.com/) for the same scenario you are describing.  It worked pretty well and has a pretty good single player simulator for when you feel like going solo.

Answer (score 9):

There's also [PokerTH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pokerth/), playable both via Internet and LAN.

Answer (score 4):

There's [AirPoker](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airpoker/id356538304?mt=8) for iPhone/iPad. Wifi and BlueTooth play.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect game for your needs : Texas Hold'em Poker 3D

Answer (score -1):

You could try [Salus Technologies](http://www.salustechnologies.com/index.asp). Pretty decent software not sure the price will fit your budget.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be poker Software?!

Comment: Sure it is. You can ping them. Offer white label or some other models for poker software.

Comment: My mistake. I looked at a firm that was selling thermostats! Same name. haha

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if zynga poker counts. We have had so much fun with zynga for our tournaments. All you need is a fb account.

Comment: Not the answer. Zynga poker is only for Internet users. I was looking for LAN (within office/home network)